# jquery загрузка контента при появлении в окне

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.

Есть ли какие нибудь плагины под jQuery, для того что бы посылать аякс запрос, когда определенный блок (допустим с id="load_on_screen") появится в области видимости на экране?

Или может как это самому сделать? Куда копать? scrollUp не подходит.

Comment: $( "#load_on_screen" ).load(function() {});

Comment: Что по вашему подразумевается под "областью видимости" ? По хорошему окно сразу же видно пользователю.Если до блока нужно скролить (т.е. он не находится на видимом участке формы с самого начала) то лучше всего сделать обработку через скролинг (т.е. высчитать определенную высоту от верха документа и выставить это значение на триггер)

Comment: @alexoander да, до блока надо скроллить. Но на странице таких несколько блоков, которые надо загружать не сразу, а при прокрутке и появлении в области видимости. И они все находятся на разном расстоянии от верха. По этому придется 3 обработчика писать. А по другому не как?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick Прочтите комментарий выше

Comment: Обработчик будет 1 - просто цифры будут разные и события разные на ответ (т.е. параметрами будут переданы в один обработчик). Других вариантов (быстрых) я не вижу т.к. я не помню таких тригеров как появление на экране.

Comment: что-то вроде triggerOnScroll(pxFromTop,callback)

Comment: можно хотябы самый скромный пример, с 2 разными высотами?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function inWindow(s){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var currentEls = $(s);
  var result = [];

    var offset = currentEls.offset();
    if(scrollTop <= offset.top && (currentEls.height() + offset.top) < (scrollTop + windowHeight))
      return true;

  return false;
}

var boxesInWindow = inWindow("#sc-2");
console.log(boxesInWindow);


$(document).scroll(function () {
   if(inWindow("#sc-2")) {
      console.log('1');
   }
});
```

```css
.sc-1 {
width:100%;
height:500px;
background:red
}
.sc-2 {
width:100%;
height:300px;
background:green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="sc-1" class="sc-1">
</div>
<div id="sc-2" class="sc-2">
</div>
```

А вообще есть библиотека [lazy load](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) как вариант её использовать

Comment: Не работает. Все время false стоит